# Confusion with scanner class -> nextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have written a basic code to read different data types. But I can not enter the string as input. What am I missing ?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int integer = read.nextInt();
    double Double = read.nextDouble();
    String string = read.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("String: %s\nDouble: %f\nInt: %d",string,Double,integer);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must "eat up" the newline character left over from the double.

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
int integer = read.nextInt();
double Double = read.nextDouble();
read.nextLine();
String string = read.nextLine();
System.out.printf("String: %s\nDouble: %f\nInt: %d",string,Double,integer);
```

The problem is that after `nextDouble()` there is still a newline character out there so the scanner reads the next line which has nothing in it...

Comment: Just to further add to this, `read.nextInt()` leaves the newline character as well. In this situation though, JAVA is hiding this fact because `read.nextDouble()` will skip over the newline when looking for the next double. `read.nextLine()` obviously will stop at the end of the line.

Comment: Oh. Wow. I get it. After this line -> read.nextDouble() the cursor moves after the double value (and stays there at the end) but not to the next line. So, I must move the cursor to the next line myself. Am I right ?